# Promise of 'Nothing' is never completed?

Tags: scala, akka, promise

I wonder why a Promise of 'Nothing' never completes when I pass "_" as completion result. I ran into this when I wanted to use a Promise to signal that something has finished:

```
  val promiseWillFinish = Promise()
  promiseWillFinish.success(_)
  // will time out
  Await.ready(promiseWillFinish, 5 seconds)
  // will return false
  println(promiseWillFinish.isCompleted)
```

For now I'm using a Promise of Unit, which works fine and is also a little more clear. But I still wonder which the code above ends in a timeout / uncompleted Promise.

I ran this with Akka 2.0 final.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no possible value of type `Nothing` whatsoever (not `null`, none at all). A promise of `Nothing` cannot be completed, just as a function with result type `Nothing` cannot return.

As there is no value of type `Nothing`, there is no way of calling success. In fact you are not calling success, you misinterpret what _ does mean here :

when you declare a `var` (and only when you declare it), you can set it to its default value with '_'.  v`ar v : Int = _` will set `v` to `0`, and `var v: String = _` will set it to `null`. If you try that with Nothing, `var v : Nothing = _` , it will crash. Again, there is no value of type `Nothing`.

On the other hand, when you write `promiseWithFinish.Success(_)` it is a shortcut for

```
x => promiseWithFinish.Success(x)
```

You are creating a function value, not using it, you are doing nothing at all.

Comment: Ok thanks. I expected that I'm misinterpreting Nothing with '_' here. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `promiseWillFinish.success(_)` means what you think it means. It is partial application, which means the result of that expression is a function. You never called the `success` method, just created a new anonymous function for the method invocation.

I guess you had a `Promise[Nothing]` and were trying to use `_` as a default value of type `Nothing`. But by definition there are *no* values of type `Nothing`. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type